# Detect if user is behind a proxy server

Tags: php, proxy

I know this question has been asked a few times but I just can't find a solution! I own a dating site and have issues with people signing up through proxies (I assume) and spamming my users and creates fake account.

How can I detect if a user is behind proxies like Vtunnel, Hidemyass, TOR etc. I understand there is no guaranteed way but sites like pof.com (plenty of fish) have excellent proxy detection.

I just need to start somewhere.. even if I can just detect the most popular proxy sites.

Comment: Check DNS blocklists.

Comment: Why not add a visual/audio CAPTCHA to your site? That'd make life difficult for the spammers, who want to sign up using automated methods.

Comment: I use email validation that works fine but I can see using Google Analytics that I get a lot of hits from Nigeria, Senegal etc and 99.9% of the time they use stolen images. I now only allow users to register if they are from selected countries.. that's why I need to detect if they're using proxy

Comment: You've still not made it clear whether or not you are sure that your registrations are not automated. If you don't know, then the CAPTCHA may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless a proxy uses special header, like `X-Forwarded-For`, you can't differentiate it from a normal user. As those 'black' proxies are not so naive (their purpose is to protect their users, remember), your only choice are IP blacklists - like the ones provided by [Project Honeypot](http://www.projecthoneypot.org/services_overview.php).

Comment: Thanks raina77ow. Found this and it seems to work fine. http://snipplr.com/view/64564/

Answer (score 4):

Dating sites and similar sites that rely on user generated content will always face this problem. A simple check would be to test the headers for anything that would indicate a proxy. This may cause false positives for some mobile connections:

```
    $proxy_headers = array(
        'HTTP_VIA',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED',
        'HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR_IP',
        'VIA',
        'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'FORWARDED_FOR',
        'X_FORWARDED',
        'FORWARDED',
        'CLIENT_IP',
        'FORWARDED_FOR_IP',
        'HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION'
    );
    foreach($proxy_headers as $x){
        if (isset($_SERVER[$x])) die("You are using a proxy!");
    }
```

This will only catch the lowest quality proxies. Anonymous and open proxies will always evade these tests so from there you could check DNS blacklists such as [project honeypot](http://www.projecthoneypot.org/) although this would still leave a gap in protection.

Without building your own elaborate system, the best way to block these fraudulent accounts would be to use a third party service such as: FraudLabs, MaxMind, or [IPQualityScore](https://www.ipqualityscore.com/). Some of these do offer a free quota of monthly lookups.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question. However, there are major development in VPN detection in the last few years that could contribute to this question. It is possible to use IP address range to detect the VPN providers after geolocation service providers gathering enough data from IP address usages.

One example is using library such as https://github.com/ip2location/ip2proxy-php which query a commercial or free IP2Proxy database for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [IPDetector](https://ipdetector.info), it's an API that contains millions of IP addresses in its database, which allows you to detect if the IP is good or not (Hosting/VPN/Proxy...)